# ¿Cómo usar Vuejs con php?

Tags: php, vue.js

¿Existe alguna librería o algo que te permita usar vuejs con php sin tener que usar webpack? No soy muy diestro con WebPack y me gustaría saber si viene algún módulo o algo configurado para usar php con vuejs.

Comment: a vuejs lo puedes invocar como se hacia con jquery con una etiqueta script al final del documento html que invoca al archivo y ya, no es necesario webpack

Comment: y podré crear componentes y todo de la misma manera?

Comment: si asi mismo, es la ventaja de Vue

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar un `framework` de php como `laravel` que ya trae incluido `vuejs`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components

Otra opción si no quieres usar Laravel es `importar` el script de `vuejs`
en tu archivo .php por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: laravel no trae por defecto a Vue

Comment: Solo hace simple su integración por medio de artisan

Comment: Te invito a leer la documentación de Laravel 5.6 https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-vue-components

Comment: Diaz te invito a que cheques a detalle lo que dices, pues trae un componente por defecto sencillo, pero si quieres que Vue funcione debes hacer npm run dev, así nadamas por que si no funcionará por que Vue solo viene nombrado como dependencia en el package.json

Comment: Alfredo si te fijas en mi respuesta solo mencioné que laravel trae incluido vuejs, y en efecto ya viene en las dependencias por eso dejé el link de la documentación donde pueden revisar como usarlo. Saludos!

Comment: Pero señores, cuanta discusión, cuando, lo que yo entiendo (si se fijan en la consulta de @Diesan Romero) es que requiere usar php sin webpack; ahora mucho menos con el gigante de Laravel. El desea usar PHP puro y VueJs nada mas.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack se necesita a fuerzas para compilar Vuejs, ahora en la nueva versión ya no usa webpack si no su propio CLI, pero teniendo un lenguaje de backend como PHP, puedes consumir el API desde tu front end (vuejs) y desplegar los datos en base al query que te regrese el api (lo podrías regresar como un objeto json/array y ya lo consumes dependiendo de tu gusto)

Answer (score 0):

yo uso laravel mix , usa webpack pero es sencillo  https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/mix , viene con laravel pero no importa puedes instalarlo en calquier tipo proyecto

Comment: Podrías colocar un pequeño ejemplo de cómo sería la implementación de laravel mix  por favor? Una respuesta con solo un link no se considera como tal.